# using a variable from aspx.cs in datalist bind in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I'm creating a shop page with three different products and every product has a diffierent table with different properties so I want to change the Datalist according to a variable passed by the url that is stored in the aspx.cs with the name item1 so I want to use item1 as a string in bind so it changes according to the stored value of item1 (item1 only changes on pageload).

[The aspx code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlIfm.png)

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#75984E" />
        
        <ItemTemplate >

            <center>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Picture") %>' Width="40%" />
            <br />
            <br />
                Artist:
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind(item1) %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
                Name
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PaintingName") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Num") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" class="button" runat="server" Text="Learn More" CommandName="LearnMore"  />
                </center>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#00CC66" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
    </asp:DataList>
```

At Label1 I tried to put item1 but it isn't working.
[The aspx.cs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk4tI.png)

```
    static string category = "";
    protected static string item1="",item2="";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["category"].ToString() != null)
            {
                category = Request.QueryString["category"].ToString() + " MH";
                
                string userSqlStr = "select * from [" + category + "]";
                if (category == "Gallery MH")
                {
                    item1 = "Artist";
                    item2 = "PaintingName";
                }else if (category == "Tool MH")
                {
                    item1 = "Brand";
                    item2 = "ToolName";
                }
                else
                {
                    item1 = "DisplayName";
                    item2 = "Price";
                }
```

Comment: Your markup has things like Picture, and painting name. In fact, from a database point of view? No, you can't have a different table for each product, or in fact each type of product. If you want different types of products, then you need a product type column in the ONE table.  No database system can and does work as you suggest. I mean, think of a accounting package. they can invoice for selling a car, selling light figures and wires. Or they sell car parts. ONE invoice system works for ANY kind of product. You can't adopt a design with different tables - you normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Databinding syntax inside the below tags,

```
<%# %>
```

You can choose Eval in your DataList.

Example:
In your **label1**,

```
Text='<%# Eval("item1")%>'
```

Comment: I want the value of the item1 not where the column's name is the value of item1